# Use nginx to serve static files from subdirectories of a given directory

Tags: nginx, static-files

I have several sets of static `.html` files on my server, and I would like use nginx to serve them directly. For example, nginx should serve an URI of the following pattern:

```
www.mysite.com/public/doc/foo/bar.html
```

with the `.html` file that is located at `/home/www-data/mysite/public/doc/foo/bar.html`. You can think of `foo` as the set name, and `bar` as the file name here.

I wonder whether the following piece of nginx config would do the job:

```
server {
    listen        8080;
    server_name   www.mysite.com mysite.com;
    error_log     /home/www-data/logs/nginx_www.error.log;
    error_page    404    /404.html;

    location /public/doc/ {
        autoindex         on;
        alias             /home/www-data/mysite/public/doc/;
    }

    location = /404.html {
        alias             /home/www-data/mysite/static/html/404.html;
    }
}
```

In other words, all requests of the pattern `/public/doc/.../....html` are going to be handled by nginx, and if any given URI is not found, a default `www.mysite.com/404.html` is returned.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

It should work, however http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias says:

> When location matches the last part of the directive’s value:
>     it is better to use the root directive instead:

which would yield:

```
server {
  listen        8080;
  server_name   www.mysite.com mysite.com;
  error_log     /home/www-data/logs/nginx_www.error.log;
  error_page    404    /404.html;

  location /public/doc/ {
    autoindex on;
    root  /home/www-data/mysite;
  } 

  location = /404.html {
    root /home/www-data/mysite/static/html;
  }       
}
```

Comment: Using 2 roots gave me problems in the past, what I usually do is use one root and alias for other locations as @AlessioCampanelli suggests

Comment: Using root is the right answer. However it does not serve the static pages for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following code.
You can also use this code to serve vuejs or reactjs static files, Just modifile the `alias` to point to the root of your file directory;

```
location /files {
    #autoindex on;
    alias  /files;
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }
```

Make sure the access permissions are right too.
`sudo chown -R 1000 /files`

Example on how to access the files `http://example.com/files/text-file.txt`