# Nginx rewrite localhost to /usr/share/nginx/static

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want every request for `http://localhost/static/` to be directed to `/usr/share/nginx/static`.

For example, it the user requests `http://localhost/static/style/style.css`, I want the server to reply with the content of `/usr/share/nginx/static/style/style.css`.

This is my code (which does not work):

```
server {
  server_name http://localhost/;
  rewrite ^/static/(.*) /usr/share/nginx/$1 permanent;
}
```

And this is the main config file:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 200;
}

http {
    # Basic Settings
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # Logging Settings
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    # Include Other Configs
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**Update**: I have a file named mysite.conf like this which does not rewrite the urls as i mentioned in the question.

```
location /static {
    root /usr/share/nginx/static;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
server_name http://localhost/;
```

by

```
server_name localhost;
```

Per https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name after the `server_name` directive you put the **server's name**, not an URL.

Also `rewrite` is to do HTTP redirections, so instead of

```
rewrite ^/static/(.*) /usr/share/nginx/$1 permanent;
```

use:

```
location /static {
    root /usr/share/nginx;
}
```

See this other answer for another example: [Use nginx to serve static files from subdirectories of a given directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806893/use-nginx-to-serve-static-files-from-subdirectories-of-a-given-directory#12807304)

Comment: I don't know why but the code does not work. Please see the main configuration file. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sKsJYKwvjs/ (I upload a file named mycnf.conf in that directory which has the code you wrote)

Comment: 1) Put configuration as text in your question and 2) "does not work" is not enough. You connect to the server? What response do you get ? What do you have in logfiles ? Etc...

Comment: A root directive in a location block is totally valid and will work, so this answer isn't incorrect, but it's important to note that if you are going to use root directives in location blocks you must include one in the parent server block first, before any location blocks. Otherwise non matching location blocks within this server will have no root.